# Unexpected NSWindow becomes key window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, keywindow

I have a main `NSWindow` in my application with a button. When the button is pressed it does something like the following:

```
NSWindow *newWindow = [NSWindow initWithContentRect:[screen frame] styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
[newWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[self.previousWindow orderOut:self];
```

This works fine most of the time, but if I have a second window open (called the "other" window) and on another screen before I press the button, the following happens:

1. My new window is created, made key, and ordered front.
2. The previous window is ordered out.
3. The "other" window is made key.

Looking at the stack trace I can see that the "other" window is being made key as the result of some notification being sent. This is not in my app so must be a Cocoa thing. Given that I am explicitly saying which window should be the key window, why is Cocoa ignoring that and changing it to something else? Is there a better way to do what I want?

This doesn't occur if all the windows are on the same screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat predictably this was fixed by swapping the order of the last two lines:

```
[self.previousWindow orderOut:self];
[newWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

I initially had concerns that doing things in this order in an application where `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` returns `YES` might cause the application to close prematurely but this does not seem to be the case.